# Define path using string value with pathlib

Tags: python, string, pathlib

I am trying to design a function that iterates over a script. The arguments of this function are `first_name` and `second_name`. Among other things, this loop should create folders and subfolders  as follows:

```
def script(first_name='', second_name=''):
  (...)
  first_name='first_name'
  second_name='second_name'
  project_path = pathlib.Path.home()/'Desktop/Project_folder'
  name_path = pathlib.Path.home()/'Desktop/Project_folder/'+first_name+second_name
  subfolder = pathlib.Path.home()/'Desktop/Project_folder/'+first_name+second_name+'/subfolder' 
  (...)
```

However, when I try to run the script, I get the following error when creating the folders:

```
script(first_name, second_name)
(...)  
>>> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'
```

Since I am not very experienced with the `pathlib` module, I was wondering whether there was a way to fix this and create folders using string values inside pathlib without specifying the full path in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths are specified using forward slashes:

```
pathlib.Path.home()/'Desktop/Project_folder' / first_name / second_name / 'subfolder'
```

Example:

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> first_name, second_name = "Force", "Bru"
>>> pathlib.Path.home()/'Desktop/Project_folder' / first_name / second_name / 'subfolder'
PosixPath('/.../Desktop/Project_folder/Force/Bru/subfolder')
>>>
```

Comment: What if I need the folder name to contain both `first_name` and `second_name`, i.e. in your example `PosixPath('/.../Desktop/Project_folder/Force_Bru/subfolder')`

Comment: @BorisDonnelly, use parentheses: `pathlib.Path.home() / "whatever" / ("Force" + "_" + "Bru")` or f-strings: `the_path / f"myfolder_{name}_{surname}" / "other_folder"`

Comment: Should there be space before and after each slashes (`/`)?  If yes why there is not any after `home()`

Comment: @alper, the slashes are actually division operators. Do you need spaces in `1/2`? Python doesn't care - it's just a matter of legibility and code style. Spaces in _strings_ matter very much, though: `"hello/" != "hello /"`.

Comment: I was considering for : `pathlib.Path.home() / "Desktop" / "Project_folder"` vs `pathlib.Path.home()/"Desktop"/"Project_folder"`

Comment: @alper, there's absolutely no difference between these because spaces between operators don't matter